# Formatting array one under one

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm searching to format my array.

```
$1 = "Allo"
$2 = "Alloo"
$3 = "Allooo"
$4 = "Alloooo"

$array1 = @("")
$array1 += $1
$array1 += $2
$array1 += $3
$array1 += $4

Write-Host $array1
```

This code returns:

```
Allo Alloo Allooo Alloooo
```

I want it to be:

```
Allo
Alloo
Allooo
Alloooo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either join the array elements with newlines:

```
Write-Host ($array1 -join "`n")
```

or set the output field separator to a newline and put the variable in double quotes:

```
$OFS = "`n"
Write-Host "$array1"
```

Comment: Thank that worked. Don't know why you have to join to make a one on one array but it's ok now !

Answer (score 0):

Set the [output field separator auto variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) (`$OFS`) to a line break, and convert the array to a string:

```
$OFS = [System.Environment]::NewLine
Write-Host "$array1"
```